# Grails performance issue with fields plugin

Tags: grails

I'm experiencing a performance problem in my Grails application. I'm using the [fields plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/fields) to render my 'create', 'edit' and 'show' scaffolding views, however when I have a lot of data in my dev database the time to render a page goes through the roof.

I tracked it down to this line in the fields plugin's `FormFieldsTagLib.buildModel` method:

```
def value = attrs.containsKey('value') ? attrs.remove('value') : propertyAccessor.value
```

It looks like when `propertyAccessor.value` references a collection containing lots of entities (in my database I have a collection of maybe ~30000 rows), they're all fetched at this point. It seems a bit wasteful as the `_field.gsp` fragment may not end up doing anything with the value anyway.

Firstly, has anyone else encountered this problem?

If not, perhaps there's something wrong in my use of the fields plugin?

Also, it occurred to me that maybe there's a way to make gorm/hibernate load only the first *n* items in the collection into memory when `myDomainObject.myCollection` is invoked, but after some googling it looks like maybe it's not possible.

EDIT:

I'm using Grails 2.2.2 and Fields plugin 1.3

Comment: Your view needs to show this relation? It's not a good idea to load it all, normally you use pagination to do it.

Comment: I really don't want to show this relation on my page at all - I've created a 'blank' _field.gsp for this property so that the fields plugin renders nothing. However, when using f:all in my scaffolding show/edit/create gsp, the fields taglib iterates over every property of my domain object and invokes 'propertyAccessor.value' on it. This isn't a problem for most properties, but it is a bit problematic when the property is a rather large collection :-)

Comment: [The docs](http://freeside.co/grails-fields/ref/Tags/all.html) says that you can define a list of attributes that will not be handled (see the 'except' attr).

Comment: Thanks - that would work I think. I'm going to try overriding the 'buildModel' method though - I don't think there's any need to put the value into the attribute map when I have access to the bean and the propertyName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by modifying the `FormFieldsTagLib.buildModel` method like this:

```
    private Map buildModel(BeanPropertyAccessor propertyAccessor, Map attrs) {
            //def value = attrs.containsKey('value') ? attrs.remove('value') : propertyAccessor.value
            def valueDefault = attrs.remove('default')
            [
                    bean: propertyAccessor.rootBean,
                    property: propertyAccessor.pathFromRoot,
                    type: propertyAccessor.propertyType,
                    beanClass: propertyAccessor.beanClass,
                    label: resolveLabelText(propertyAccessor, attrs),
                    //value: (value instanceof Number || value instanceof Boolean || value) ? value : valueDefault,
                    constraints: propertyAccessor.constraints,
                    persistentProperty: propertyAccessor.persistentProperty,
                    errors: propertyAccessor.errors.collect { message(error: it) },
                    required: attrs.containsKey("required") ? Boolean.valueOf(attrs.remove('required')) : propertyAccessor.required,
                    invalid: attrs.containsKey("invalid") ? Boolean.valueOf(attrs.remove('invalid')) : propertyAccessor.invalid,
                    prefix: resolvePrefix(attrs.remove('prefix')),
            ]
    }
```

Now that I've removed the `value` property from the model I have to get hold of my property value in each `_field.gsp` like this:

`${bean."${propertyName}"}`

but I think that's a small price to pay for much better performance when dealing with large collections.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem coming from the plugin, it's a data model issue, which is to be resolved with modeling issues.

It seems your collection is eagerly fetched, and you should verify this point at first, see [Docs on lazy & eager fetching](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#fetching)

What you're talking about the "n first items in memory" is called `batch fetching` and load rows by group of `n` members

You can also keep your page to display this field, as [commented by @Sérgio Michels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703999/grails-performance-issue-with-fields-plugin/20704555#comment31011037_20703999)

Comment: Hi Grooveek, my collection isn't being eagerly fetched. When I load the enclosing entity, my collection is not loaded at this point. Only when entity.myCollection is invoked.

Comment: OK. Collections are known to be performance-killer in Grails apps. We totally removed them in ours (we have rows referencing thousands of other rows). You can watch [this inspiring talk](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) if you want to go this way

Comment: Ah I've seen that talk actually. He's a clever chap, that Mr Beckwith :-)